# In storage.mode(from) <- "double" : NAs introduced by coercion

Tags: r, bioinformatics, seurat

I am using `Seurat` and trying to analyze the data set that installed from GEO. But I am getting the following error.

I am trying the tSNE plot using R and `Seurat`, but I received the error message about `CreateSeuratObject`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(Seurat)
library(ggplot2)
cancer.rna <- read.csv2(file = "/Users/desktop/GSE84133/GSM2230757_human1_umifm_countsnew3.csv", sep = ",",header = TRUE, row.names = NULL)
dim(cancer.rna)
[1] 16381  1651
cancer.rna[1:5, 1:5]
       X TGCCTCAC.TGGGATTC AGAGACTA.GATTGCGA GAGGGAGGTA.GAAGGCTT GAGAGAGTAT.CCTATTCA
1   A1BG                 0                 0                   0                   0
2   A1CF                 0                 0                   0                   2
3    A2M                 4                 0                   0                   0
4  A2ML1                 0                 0                   0                   0
5 A4GALT                 0                 0                   0                   0
cancer <- CreateSeuratObject(counts = cancer.rna, project = "GSE84133", min.cells = 3,  min.features = 200) 
Warning message:
In storage.mode(from) <- "double" : NAs introduced by coercion
```

I had an error message: In storage.mode(from) <- "double" : NAs introduced by coercion. Please tell me how to work it.

Answer (score 1):

This going because function `read.table` not specified column name and `CreateSeuratObject` training calculate mean value of column with names X. Simply set `row.names = 1` in `read.table`, for point to names column.